# Bluetooth / Bluez: No reply to ping over bnepX interface

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have trialed to use Network, NAP profiles on Bluetooth.

On Host, `xUbuntu 13.04` I have followed as [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/258370/166523).

This Host or XUbuntu machine is `behind proxy` & runs on `virtual machine`.

It is installed with `Bluetooth` version `4.101`

On embedded board, `ping 173.194.112.211` responds as below:

```
PING 173.194.112.211 (173.194.112.211) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from 173.194.112.211: icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=336 ms
```

On embedded board, `ifconfig` shows as below:

```
bnep0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3E:DA:FB:6C:EE:BC  
          inet addr:10.220.129.178  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::3cda:fbff:fe6c:eebc/64 Scope:Link  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:458 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500  
          RX bytes:1793 (1.7 KiB)  TX bytes:36870 (36.0 KiB)  

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0C:23:C0:80:C0:E8  
          inet addr:10.122.83.127  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e23:c0ff:fe80:c0e8/64 Scope:Link  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:24555 errors:0 dropped:611 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:20647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
          RX bytes:3374125 (3.2 MiB)  TX bytes:5878612 (5.6 MiB)  

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0  
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host  
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1  
          RX packets:25809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:25809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0   
          RX bytes:3824780 (3.6 MiB)  TX bytes:3824780 (3.6 MiB)  

polo0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:00:00:00:01  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ff:fe00:1/64 Scope:Link  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:65536  Metric:1  
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:117357 (114.6 KiB)
```

On embedded board, I issue command: `ping -I bnep0 173.194.112.211`
This is google IP address by the way :)

After long time, I press `Ctrl + c`, it gives this:

```
PING 173.194.112.211 (173.194.112.211): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 173.194.112.211 ping statistics ---
541 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

On embedded board, I also trialed changing bnep0 inet addr to: 10.122.83.128.
For sure no one has this IP address.

It did not work...

`hcidump -X` shows these packets when I ping, not other times.

```
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 2.4
device: hci0 snap_len: 1028 filter: 0xffffffff
> ACL data: handle 38 flags 0x02 dlen 47
    L2CAP(d): cid 0x0042 len 43 [psm 0]
      0000: 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 3e  da fb 6c ee bc 08 06 00  .......>..l.....
      0010: 01 08 00 06 04 00 01 3e  da fb 6c ee bc 0a dc 81  .......>..l.....
      0020: b2 00 00 00 00 00 00 ad  c2 70 d3                 .........p.
> ACL data: handle 38 flags 0x02 dlen 47
    L2CAP(d): cid 0x0042 len 43 [psm 0]
      0000: 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 3e  da fb 6c ee bc 08 06 00  .......>..l.....
      0010: 01 08 00 06 04 00 01 3e  da fb 6c ee bc 0a dc 81  .......>..l.....
      0020: b2 00 00 00 00 00 00 ad  c2 70 d3                 .........p.
> ACL data: handle 38 flags 0x02 dlen 47
    L2CAP(d): cid 0x0042 len 43 [psm 0]
      0000: 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 3e  da fb 6c ee bc 08 06 00  .......>..l.....
      0010: 01 08 00 06 04 00 01 3e  da fb 6c ee bc 0a dc 81  .......>..l.....
      0020: b2 00 00 00 00 00 00 ad  c2 70 d3                 .........p.
```

**I wish to access internet On embedded board, over Bluetooth, via xUbuntu's Ethernet's internet connection, NOT Ethernet of embedded board.**

Someone please help me to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured bnep0 network interface on xUbuntu 13.04 with local IP address and it workded :)

`# ifconfig bnep0 192.168.1.3 up`

I also guess that command `route` also helped.

The ping works, however, there is packet loss...